# Rails routes and has_one relationship causing incorrect route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a User and cabinet model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :cabinet

  after_create :create_cabinet

  // Omitted code

  def create_cabinet
    Cabinet.create(user_id: id)
  end
end
```

-

```
class Cabinet < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :cabinet_ingredients, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :ingredients, through: :cabinet_ingredients
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :user_id, :cabinet_ingredients_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cabinet_ingredients

end
```

-

```
Mixology::Application.routes.draw do

  // Omitted code
  resource  :cabinet

end
```

I keep getting my route whenever I go to my users cabinet to come back as cabinet.1... and then when I try to access any of the cabinet_ingredients I get an error saying that cabinet_ingredient.5 (the id of the cabinet_ingredient) cant be found...

Not sure why I'm getting this.. My `rake routes` returns:

```
    cabinet     POST   /cabinet(.:format)                 cabinets#create
    new_cabinet GET    /cabinet/new(.:format)             cabinets#new
   edit_cabinet GET    /cabinet/edit(.:format)            cabinets#edit
                GET    /cabinet(.:format)                 cabinets#show
                PUT    /cabinet(.:format)                 cabinets#update
                DELETE /cabinet(.:format)                 cabinets#destroy
```

Cabinet show view

```
%table.table.table-striped
  %thead
    %tr
      %th My Ingredients
      %th ID
  %tbody
    - @cabinet.cabinet_ingredients.each do |ci|
      %tr
        %td= ci.ingredient.name
        %td= link_to "delete from cabinet", cabinet_path(ci), method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?"
```

Cabinet controller:

```
  def show
    @cabinet = current_user.cabinet
  end

  def edit
    @cabinet = current_user.cabinet
    @ingredients = Ingredient.all
  end

  def update
    @ingredients = Ingredient.all
    @cabinet = current_user.cabinet
    if @cabinet.update_attributes(params[:cabinet])
      redirect_to @cabinet
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    ingredient = CabinetIngredient.find(params[:id])
    ingredient.destroy
    redirect_to cabinet_path
  end
```

Comment: You don't include any route or controller information about cabinet_ingredient, but the problem is likely there.  If you state resource instead of resources in the routes, then there is only one cabinet, so the route is not expecting you to use an id for cabinet.

Comment: can you please show the link you want to call for the route?

Comment: Added cabinet_ingredient code. I don't have a route for the cabinet ingredients, I do all the work inside the cabinet

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a similar problem, here is the solution that I came up with:

Instead of doing the destroy in the cabinet controller, I created a cabinet_ingredients controller and added a destroy action

```
class CabinetIngredientsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    ingredient = current_user.cabinet.cabinet_ingredients.find(params[:id])
    ingredient.destroy
    redirect_to cabinet_path
  end
end
```

and then updated the cabinet show to route to the cabinet_ingredients controller

```
%table.table.table-striped
  %thead
    %tr
      %th My Ingredients
      %th ID
  %tbody
    - @cabinet.cabinet_ingredients.each do |ci|
      %tr
        %td= ci.ingredient.name
        %td= link_to "delete from cabinet", cabinet_ingredient_path(ci), method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?"
```

Then lastly the routes:

```
Mixology::Application.routes.draw do

  resource  :cabinet
  resources :cabinet_ingredients

end
```